# Selection sort Char C

Tags: c, sorting, char, logic

this is a program I have written that is supposed to sort the the individual chars of words in alphabetical order using a selection sort method.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char str[100];

void alphaOrder(){

for(int i=0;str[i]!='\0';++i){                                    //iterate until end of entered string
   if(str[i+1]==' ' || str[i+1]==NULL){        // iterate until end of current word    

          int wordLength=0;                                                 // finds amount of letters in current word    
          for(int j=i;j>=0 && str[j]!=' ';j--){                    
            wordLength+=1;
          }
          int smallest=1000;                   
          int prv = 1000;

          for(int k=0;k != wordLength;++k){
                int counter=0;                                     //loops through letters in word printing and storing the smallest
                while(counter!=wordLength){     
                    if(k==0){                                                   // this if loop only occurs during for 1st char of word
                        if(str[i-counter] < smallest){
                        smallest=str[i-counter];
                         }
                    }

                    else{
                        if(str[i-counter] > smallest && str[i-counter] < prv){
                            smallest=str[i-counter];
                            prv=smallest;
                        }
                    }
                 ++counter;
                }   
                printf("%c",smallest);      
            }           
    }
}
```

But the issue i'm having stems from the logic in this snippet:

```
for(int k=0;k != wordLength;++k){
                int counter=0;                                     //loops through letters in word printing and storing the smallest
                while(counter!=wordLength){     
                    if(k==0){                                                   // this if loop only occurs during for 1st char of word
                        if(str[i-counter] < smallest){
                        smallest=str[i-counter];
                         }
                    }

                    else{
                        if(str[i-counter] > smallest && str[i-counter] < prv){
                            smallest=str[i-counter];
                            prv=smallest;
                        }
                    }
                 ++counter;
                }   
                printf("%c",smallest);
```

for example:

```
input: hello world
output:eoooo ddddd
```

I know that the problem stems from the logic but it's been a week and I still cannot properly implement the selection sort algorithm or figure out what exactly that I need.
so any advice or suggestions are greatly welcomed

Comment: What have you done to debug this?  What have you printed?  What are you tracking in your debugger?  What is the value of `wordLength` when processing `world`?  Why are you using a global variable in the function?  You should be passing the string to be sorted to the function. AFAICS, you try to 'sort' first `hello`, then `ello`, and then `llo`, etc. But you aren't sorting the string; you're printing out characters as you go and not rearranging them. Aren't you supposed to rearrange the data?  You should split the function into at least two — one to split, one to sort.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void alphaOrder(char *str){
    char *p = str;
    while(*p){
        while(isspace((unsigned char)*p))
            ++p;//skip space
        if(!*p)//end of string?
            break;
        char *word = p;//top of word
        while(*p && !isspace((unsigned char)*p))
            ++p;//in word
        //selection sort
        int word_length = p - word;
        for(int i = 0; i < word_length -1; ++i){
            int smallest = i;
            for(int j = i + 1; j < word_length; ++j){
                if(word[smallest] > word[j])
                    smallest = j;
            }
            if(i != smallest){
                char temp = word[i];
                word[i] = word[smallest];
                word[smallest] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(void){
    char str[100+1];
    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
    alphaOrder(str);
    puts(str);
}
```

Comment: If the _word_ consists only of alphabets, use `isalpha` instead of `isspace`.